# How to use C# to open windows explorer in "select/open file mode"

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm using Unity with C#.

I am making an Asset Maker for a game I am working on. I want to use windows explorer to browse and select a file that will be loaded into the program. To be more specific, I want to press a button in unity that will run a method that will open windows explorer and allow for the user to browse and select an image. This image file will be copied and placed into a directory inside the assets/resources folder in unity.

I am not sure what methods to use to accomplish this but here is where I'm at:

```
 System.Diagnostics.Process p = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
 p.StartInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo("explorer.exe");
 p.StartInfo.Arguments = "";
 p.Start();
```

I feel like I need to put something in the "p.StartInfor.Arguments" property but I can find anything good enough online about it other that things like "/select" ...etc which doesn't allow for the user to "Browse". Or there might be something completely different I need to be using. Please help! Thank you!

Comment: Maybe [OpenFilePanel](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorUtility.OpenFilePanel.html)? In general, you don't launch Explorer, you open an `Open File Dialog`. Lots of hits of various quality found searching on those words + `Unity`.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever That is the exact thing I was looking for thank you soooo much!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "/select" (without quotes) as the argument
Full Code is

```
System.Diagnostics.Process p = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
 p.StartInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo("explorer.exe");
 p.StartInfo.Arguments = "\select";
 p.Start();
```

Comment: As I stated in my question, "/select" is not what I'm looking for as it does not do what I need. In fact, it does nothing different from just leaving arguments blank...